# Google Play Games services keeps crashing with everything added

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have setup Google Play Games Services in my game and it does not see to work. Everytime I run the application, the application crashes. I have been searching the internet for fixes but nothing is working.

I have set up my meta-data here:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
    android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Also, I have added the internet and get accounts permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

I have imported everything through the Android tab and added library's.

Before, I had Java Build Path libraries and removed them to try to fix this.

To call this I initialise the GoogleApiClient here:

```
client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();
```

And I connected with the `client.connect();` method.

From LogCat I get a message from my package saying:

```
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686): Process: com.ajayinkingston.tapthatsquare, PID: 23686
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.b(Unknown Source)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.g(Unknown Source)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$b.gU(Unknown Source)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-23 18:23:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(23686):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And if I look at all messages I see a message beforehand saying:

```
10-23 18:23:38.569: E/ValidateServiceOp(14255): Using Google Play games services requires a metadata tag with the name "com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" in the application tag of the manifest for com.ajayinkingston.tapthatsquare
```

My app_id is in the strings.xml folder in res/values. It was in games-ids.xml but i moved in trying to fix it.

```
<string name="app_id">************</string>
<string name="achievement_wow_great_start">code here</string>
<string name="achievement_fast_i_want_to_play_fast">code here</string>
<string name="achievement_first_try">code here</string>
<string name="achievement_bonus">code here</string>
<string name="achievement_expert">code here</string>
<string name="leaderboard_highscore">code here</string>
```

I have also tried moving everything to a new workspace and deleting bin/gen folders

I am very confused and have tried everything I could find.

Thanks

Comment: A couple quick things to check: is app_id defined somewhere (such as res/values/ids.xml?  Does the value match the id from the games console?

Comment: I just added my strings.xml file listing the strings

Comment: I have double checked and copy and pasted it again and again.

Comment: I have just added the area where I placed it. Is that the correct area. I'm thinking that is where I made my mistake but every article I have seen hasn't been to clear.

Comment: The sample code is pretty straight forward and has good step by step instructions. You could try running one of those and maybe  that will help figure out what's going on in your app. https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

Comment: The sample doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: The sample actually does work but I had to restart eclipse because of the DexPathList error. I will try to find what I did wrong compared to the sample.

Comment: Everything seems to be the same and I don't know why it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out that I made a typo. For the manifest I typed

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

But you have to add `games`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```